# Evaluate $ I_1=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos 3x}{5+6x+9x^2}dx $ using Fourier transform.

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform

> Evaluate integral:
>   $$
> I_1=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos 3x}{5+6x+9x^2}dx
> $$

I used Fourier transform in the following form:
$$
\hat{f}(y)=F[f(x)]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{ixy}dx
$$
Therefore, I have the following properties and formulas:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&F[f(kx)]=\frac{1}{|k|}\hat{f}\left(\frac{y}{k}\right),\ \ k\ne 0\\
&F[f(x-a)]=e^{iay}\hat{f}(y),\ \ a\in\mathbb{R}\\
&F\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]=\pi\cdot e^{-|y|}
\end{aligned}
$$

#### So, here is my attempt:

Suppose $I_2=i\cdot\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin 3x}{5+6x+9x^2}dx$. Therefore:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I_1+I_2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{3ix}}{5+6x+9x^2}dx=F\left[\frac{1}{5+6x+9x^2}\right]\Bigm|_{y=3}\\
&\frac{1}{5+6x+9x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1}=g(x)\\
&F\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)^2 +1}\right]=\frac{2}{3}\pi e^{-\frac{2}{3}|y|}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ 
F\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3x}{2}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2 +1}\right]=e^{-\frac{1}{2}iy}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\pi e^{-\frac{2}{3}|y|}\\
&F[g(x)]=\frac{\pi}{6}e^{-\frac{1}{2}iy}e^{-\frac{2}{3}|y|}\Rightarrow I_1+I_2=\frac{\pi}{6}e^{-\frac{3}{2}i}\cdot e^{-2}\\
&I_1=\text{Re}(I_1+I_2)=\frac{\pi}{6e^2}\cos\frac{3}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
However, the correct answer is this: $$I_1=\frac{\pi}{6e^2}\cos 1$$

I've tried different approaches, and yet I don't realize what is wrong with my solution. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake when changing variables?
$$F\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3x}{2}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2 +1}\right]=e^{-\frac{1}{3}iy}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\pi e^{-\frac{2}{3}|y|}$$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Don't get what? It's $x=2u/3 - 1/3$ not $x=2u/3 - 1/2$.

Comment: Because it is $$3x/2+1/2=3/2(x+1/3) \, .$$

Comment: All right. So, I have to use $F[f(x+a)]$ formula before using this one $F[f(kx)]$ ? I thought there is no difference.

Comment: Your formula clearly says $x$ is isolated with coefficient $1$, so you need to get in correct form before applying it.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: You don't have to apply $F[f(x+a)]$ first. You can also apply $$F[f(kx)]=\frac{1}{|k|}\hat{f}\left(\frac{y}{k}\right)$$ first. But then you need to keep in mind that your new parameter is $y/k=y/(3/2)=2y/3$. Then you apply the shift formula with $a=-1/2$ to the fourier transform with parameter $2y/3$ instead of just $y$.

Comment: Just one more note. In order to not get mixed up, it might be better to write $F[f(x)](y)$ instead of just $F[f(x)]$ where you neglect the parameter dependence, which is probably the point of confusion where you got stuck. To see this, consider the following sequence of equalities $$F\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1}\right](y)=\frac{2}{3} \, F\left[\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1}\right]\left(\frac{2y}{3}\right) = \frac{2}{3} \, e^{-i1/2\cdot 2y/3} \, F\left[\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right]\left(\frac{2y}{3}\right) \, . $$